# Disable warning , notice on response in localhost

Tags: php

I am getting PHP warning on localhost servers

`<br /> <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: stdClass::$sname in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\profits\api\product_modification_menu_v2.php</b> on line <b>0</b><br /> {"STATUS":"success","MESSAGE":"Updated Successfully"}`

Which leads to a problem in my front end when it tries to catch the response.

How do I make sure, these notices doesn't come ?

Comment: _..How do I make sure, these notices doesn't come ?.._ I'd fix the issues related to the warnings instead of supressing those

Comment: Fix it, dont ignore it. Eventually one of those will be the reason you spend hours looking for an issue that makes no sense because you cannot see any of these useful hints